# prove ceiling(x) - x = fp(1-x)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

prove ceiling(x) - x = fp(1-x)

using the facts:

-> 0 <= fp(x) < 1, and fp(x) = x - ⌊x⌋

-> fp(1-x) =  1 - χℤ (x) - fp(x)

-> the real interval  [x,x+1) or (x,x+1] has an integer

Here is my proof
since fp(1-x) = 1 - χℤ (x) - fp(x), then fp(1-x) = 1 - 1 - (x - ⌊x⌋) or fp(1-x) = 1 - 0 - (x - ⌊x⌋) because χℤ (x) = 1 if x∈ℤ and o if x∉ℤ.  Then we get fp(1-x) = - (x - ⌊x⌋) or fp(1-x) = 1 - (x - ⌊x⌋). so fp(1-x) = - (x - ⌊x⌋) = cealing(x) - x or fp(1-x) = 1 - (x - ⌊x⌋) = 1 + cealing(x) - x

can someone help me on this.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that for any $x$, $\{1-x\}=1-\{x\}$ where $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part. Now, $ceil(x)-x=[x]+1-x=1-(x-[x])=1-\{x\}=\{1-x\}$ where by definition, $[x]=x-\{x\}$.

Comment: If x=0, {1-x} = {1} = 0, but 1-{x} = 1.

Comment: Oh, right. I was too hasty with the argument. Sorry.